# The trivial loci of a family of sheaves is closed subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $V, T$ be varieties, $V$ is complete, and $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $V \times T$. Then why $\{t \in T | L_t \rm{is~ trivial} \}$ is closed in $T$?

The reason given is "Because this set is the intersection of $Supp(q_* L)$ and $Supp(q_* L^\vee)$". I did not figure out why.

I was wondering that the above result should follow from the result that: if $L$ is an invertible sheaf on complete variety, then $L$ is trivial <=> $H^0(V , L), H^0(V , L^\vee)$ are both nonzero. However, I don't know how to deduce from this result.

Comment: Please clarify What $T$ is?

Comment: $T$ is a variety, but I am not sure if $L$ has to be flat over $T$. If necessary, please feel free to add that condition as well.